# Correct algorithm to determinate if the user is really inside/outside a region

Tags: gps, area, circle, geofencing

first time here.

I'm currently building a system that control the user GPS position in order to turn on/turn off some stuff inside user's house.

For example, if the user leave the house we must turn off heaters, when the user return home, the opposite.

The user, obviously, must set a radius (for example 2miles, the center of the circle is his house) that actually act as a geofence.

Now it comes the problem, how can I determinate if the user is really inside the geofence and not passing by?

At this time the logic that I actually implemented is the following (and I really think this is NOT the correct way):

1. Get all GPS points of the user of last 2mins.
2. Calculate the center of the bounds of the GPS points retrived and the **distance** from this to the geofence's center.
3. Check if the distance is more/less of the radius.

**EDIT The problem that I am trying to resolve is this:**

[image: As you can see the user is entered the region, but after sometime, he leaves]

The orange dots are the GPS points of the user. He enter and after sometime, he leaves.

Comment: A circle is a special case of a region.  A more general solution would involve [tag:point-in-polygon].

Comment: I guess crossing the border is the best. Going in = switches on, going ò out  = off

Comment: Ehm, is not that easy. I admit that I simplified the scenario because "turn on" and "turn off" hide a lot of other actions to do, so is not efficent what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it very simple. Choose a threshold t such that after t seconds with all samples inside the radius, the system is activated. Your "passing by" example just looks like a case of the radius being too large.

If you really want to do something more complex, you could look at the difference between average distance to the geofence centre from consecutive samples and insist on having the past n samples be both inside the geofence and with decreasing average distance to the centre. This requires care, though, as it might not work if, for example, there are unusual street layouts that force the user to approach their home in a 'Z' shape.

Comment: I prefer your first advice, so actually is not that far from what I have just implemented.

Answer (score 0):

What computer programming language are you using?  If you are using Python and have access to ArcGIS then you could store the buffer as a polygon feature class, the location as a point. Then use the feature geometry method *Contains* to return true if the point is within the polygon.
Here is a link to the arcpy geometry object---
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm

Comment: I am using nodejs, but I don't think is what I mean. I modified the question, hope it helps.